# How can i post data with classname in Retrofit

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2

I post data with retrofit my webservice but it return null because of i post like this;

```
{"username":"asd","password":"123"}
```

but i want to post like this;

```
{user:{"username":"asd","password":"123"}}
```

These are my entities and calling methods;

```
public class User {

@SerializedName("username")
@Expose
public String username;

@SerializedName("password")
@Expose
public String password;
}
```

My call service interface like this;

```
  @POST("/test/Logon")
Call<Result> getLogon(@Body User user);
```

***I don't want to use extra class for passing User on it.***

Comment: just make new `JSONObject` with key `user` and value is current you are passing

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  @POST("/test/Logon")
Call<Result> getLogon(@Body Map<String,Object> user);
```

And white passing object to getLogon

```
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap();
map.put("user",userObject);
getLogon(map)
```